# I cannot open windows inside PYQT5 function

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, pyqt5

I recently started writing a simple messenger in python. I need to open the main window in a function after a signal from the server that the user is logged into the account, but the program crashes if it tries to open the main window or close the login window (ChildWindow). The program just freezes in place without printing an error to the console.
I tried to move open windows to another Sign_in function and everything worked, but as soon as I try to open a window in get_text, the program freezes and crashes.
I know that there are similar solutions to this problem, but I just can't figure out how to solve my problem.

server.py

```
import pickle
import socket
import threading


class Server(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self):  
        super().__init__(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.bind(("192.168.0.3", 9090))
        self.listen()
        print("Server Listen")
        self.users = []  # List of all users
        self.users_ip = []  # List of all users-ip

        self.login_password = {"T": "N", "Rahnel": "2002", "Madina": "BBox",
                               "Stark": "Stark", "Mark": "Mark", "Gleb": "2002"}  # "Data base"

    def send_data(self, data):  # Send text to all users (in the list)
        try:
            for user in reversed(self.users):
                count_users = len(self.users)
                print(f"Кол-во польз.---> {count_users}")
                count_users = str(count_users).encode('utf-8')
                all_data = [count_users, data]
                user.send(pickle.dumps(all_data))
                print(f"ДАННЫЕ ОТ СЕРВЕРА ----> {all_data}")
        except Exception as a:
            print(f"_SEND_DATA ---> {a}")

    def listen_socket(self, ip_user, socket_user=None, ):  # Accept text from client

        print("Listen User")
        try:
            while True:
                self.data_s = socket_user.recv(2048)  # Accepting a message
                self.data_s = pickle.loads(self.data_s)
                if self.data_s[0] == "TRY_TO_ENTRY":  # If there is an ENTRY signal from the client, we start the process of checking the data from the user
                    self.user_sign_in(self.data_s)
                else:
                    print(f"User send ---> {self.data_s[0]}")  # If the first message is not INPUT, then just turn on the normal operation mode (at the moment)

                    self.send_data(self.data_s)
        except Exception as a:
            """
            
            If the client is disconnected, then we remove it from the user array and 
            the IP array
            users at the moment so. (While it works and thank God)
            """
            self.users.remove(socket_user)
            self.users_ip.remove(ip_user)
            print(f"_LISTEN_SOCKET ---> {a}")
            print(self.users)
            print("__________________________________________")

    def user_sign_in(self, data): 
# Function for checking the password and login from the client with the database
        print(data)
        if self.login_password.get(data[1]) == data[2]:
            signIN = ["USER IS SIGN"]
            print("USER IS SIGN")
            for user in self.users:
                user.send(pickle.dumps(signIN))
        else:
            no_sign_in = ["USER IS NOT SIGN"]
            print("USER IS SIGN")
            for user in self.users:
                user.send(pickle.dumps(no_sign_in))

    def start_server(self):

        while True:

            users_socket, address = self.accept()
            if address[0] not in self.users_ip:
                """
                
                Checking that the user could not run many clients on one pc
                
                """
                self.users_ip.append(address[0])

              
                print("Users accept!" + address[0])  
                self.users.append(users_socket)  #  Add new user in list
                threading.Thread(target=self.listen_socket, args=(address[0], 
users_socket)).start()


            else:
                print("He is already here")


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Start
    server = Server()
    server.start_server()
```

Client

```
import pickle
import socket
import sys
import threading

import keyboard
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

from LandP import Ui_LandP  #ChildWindow




class Client(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self):  # Connect to server
        super().__init__()
        self.connect(("178.70.167.46", 9090))

    def send_data(self, data_text):  # Send data on server
        self.send(data_text)


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self):

        self.cl = Client()
        global ChildWindow
        ChildWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.LPForm = Ui_LandP()
        self.LPForm.setupUi(ChildWindow)
        self.thr = threading.Thread(target=self.get_text).start()

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(658, 490)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 54, 641, 231))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 30, 133, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(294, 10, 47, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferDefault)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 310, 639, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(195, 350, 250, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 410, 173, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.send_text)
        self.LPForm.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Sign_in)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.send_for_Enter = threading.Thread(target=self.send_text_with_enter).start()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):

        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отправить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во пользователей онлайн"))

    def Sign_in(self):  # ChildWindow

        login = self.LPForm.lineEdit.text()
        password = self.LPForm.lineEdit_2.text()

        data_of_sign = ["TRY_TO_ENTRY", login, password]
        data_of_sign = pickle.dumps(data_of_sign)
        self.send_text()

        self.cl.send_data(data_of_sign)

    def get_text(self):
        # We receive text from the server USING the client (Client)

        while True:
            try:

                data = self.cl.recv(2048)
                data = pickle.loads(data)
                print(data)

                if data[0] == "USER IS SIGN":  # Login check (Server confirmed login with a message)
                    print("YOU GOT IN")
                    MainWindow.show()
                    ChildWindow.close()





                else:  # if it is NOT a signal from the server to enter the account
                    print("NOPE")

                    print(f"message from server ---> {data}")
                    message = data[1]
                    print(f"message[1] from server ---> {message}")
                    self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)

                    self.textBrowser.append(message)
                    count_users = data[0]
                    self.label_2.setText(f"Users in online: {count_users.decode('utf-8')}")
            except EOFError:
                """
                Curve check to run the program more than once on one pc, 
                so that one user cannot run the client many times
                """

                print("EOFError")
                self.label_2.setText("!ВЫ ЗАПУСТИЛИ !")
                self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)

                input()

            except Exception as err:
                print(err)

                self.label_2.setText("!SERVER STOPPED WORK!")
                self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
                input()

    def send_text_with_enter(
            self):  # Sending text to the client by pressing Enter NOT A CRAWLER BUT A TEMPORARY MEASURE

        while True:
            keyboard.wait('Enter')
            if (self.lineEdit_2.text()).strip() != "":
                text = (self.lineEdit.text()).strip() + ": " + (self.lineEdit_2.text()).strip()
                text = pickle.dumps(text)
                self.cl.send_data(text)
                self.lineEdit_2.setText("")

    def shotdown(self):  # К хренам обрумаем ему все его костыли и програ умирает от нажатия на Крестик
        print("ОКНО ЗАКРЫТО ПО ЖЕЛАНИЮ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ")
        raise Exception

    def send_text(self):  # Sending text to client on button click

        if (self.lineEdit_2.text()).strip() != "":
            text = (self.lineEdit.text()).strip() + ": " + (self.lineEdit_2.text()).strip()
            text = pickle.dumps(text)
            print(f"Сообщение отправленное на сервер в байтах ---> {text}")
            self.cl.send_data(text)
            self.lineEdit_2.setText("")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    global MainWindow
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi()

    ChildWindow.show()
    app.lastWindowClosed.connect(ui.shotdown)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

LandP (ChildWindow)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class Ui_LandP(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(435, 253)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(435, 253))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(435, 253))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(201, 50, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 140, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(98, 210, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(202, 210, 145, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 72, 245, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 160, 245, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)






        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit, self.lineEdit_2)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Логин"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пороль"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войти"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Создать аккаунт"))
```

Comment: UI elements are ***not*** thread safe. Also, you should *never* use a while loop in a UI environment unless you're completely sure that it exits almost instantly. If you want to get the result of an input field when the return key is pressed, using `keyboard.wait` and threads is *not* the solution: you should connect to the QLineEdit's [`returnPressed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#returnPressed) signal instead.

Comment: Besides that, editing (or mimicking) the output of a pyuic generated file is considered bad practice. Please read more on how to *properly* use those files on the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Globals should also be avoided, as they often lead to silent errors and bugs that are difficult to track.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm just starting to learn this and I will take any advice into account. Thanks for taking the time to read my code. Thanks